# std vector push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer error

Tags: c++, qt, vector, stl

I have this qt application, in the header file I have

```
class report_intro: public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    report_intro(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~report_intro(void);
    int nextId() const;
private:
    Ui::Rep_Wiz_Intro ui; 
    QWidget *pWnd;
    std::vector<int> m_vTests;
    int m_iNumTest; 
};
```

In the Cpp file I have

```
int report_intro::nextId() const
{   
    int i;
    // check to see which check box was checked 
    for (i=1; i<m_iNumTest; i++)
    {
        QString str = QString("checkBox_T%1").arg(i);
        if ((ui.groupBox_tests->findChild<QCheckBox *>(str))->isChecked())
            m_vTests.push_back(i); // **** here is the error****
    }
        return newreport::report_page; 
}
```

And I am getting this error :

```
error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: `report_intro::nextId` is const member function, so you can't modifying member variable inside it, including calling `std::vector::push_back` on `m_vTests`.

Comment: hmmm...Can I create a function wrapper to do that (like another function inside nextId?

Comment: @songyuanyao Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @Samer I don't think it would work. If it has to be a const member function, you might make `m_vTests` mutable as NathanOliver said.

Comment: @Barry I hesitated to post it as answer because I'm not sure what's OP want to do indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int report_intro::nextId() const` is marked as `const`.  That specifier promises you will not alter the state/members of the class.

`m_vTests.push_back(i);` violates that as you are changing `m_vTests`.

You either need to drop the `const` specifier from the function or declare `m_vTests` as `mutable` so it can be modified in `const` functions.

Comment: @Samer Yes it will work.  `mutable` has existed since the beginning of the language and is used for cases where you do need to modify something that has no effect in the class but it is done in a `const` function.  something like locking and unlocking a mutex for example.